# insert trigger after update on one table

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
create or replace trigger tgr_insertinworkdone
after update on workassgined
referencing new as new old as old
for each row
declare 
    workdonetemp number(15);
begin
    select max(workdoneid) into workdonetemp from workdone;
if :new.complete_status = 'T' 
then 
    insert into workdone(workdoneid,workid,workdatedate,type,status)
    values(workdonetemp+1,old.docid,old.taskdate,'C','Completed');
end if;
end;
```

getting error OR:00984 column not allowed here.
here i'm tryin gto insert one row in workdone table based on complete flag Ture in workassgined table, once this flag becomes 'T' then one row should be inserted into workdonw table. any help?

Comment: The syntax is to prefix `old` and `new ` namespaces with a colon. So `:old.docid` not `old.docid`

Answer (score 0):

Guess your are missing the colons(:) before the old
Should be

nsert into workdone(workdoneid,workid,workdatedate,type,status)
    values(workdonetemp+1,:old.docid,:old.taskdate,'C','Completed');

Comment: Thank you very much sir!,its working now.My mistake.